# Wordpress theme folder - replacement?

Tags: wordpress, parsing, themes, corrupt

I've recently had a problem with my wordpress site after updating to the latest version of wordpress. The logo vanished.

The theme support said to replace my entire theme folder with a fresh updated version from their site. Now all I can see is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage99/al/ot/of/alotofbradshaw.com/public_html/blog/wp-content/themes/stockholm/framework/lib/qode.layout.php on line 2695

I'm guessing this is not good.

Anyone have an ideas what has happened? I know this is probabaly a vague question but any advice would be more than welcome.

Comment: I see a wp-config error on your site. "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage99/al/ot/of/alotofbradshaw.com/public_html/blog/wp-config.php on line 35"

Tell me which folder did you replace? Where did you put the theme? Do you have your old theme somewhere as backup?

Comment: Hi, I replaced the entire theme folder for my theme stockholm. As they said to do on their support page. No, stupid I know, I dont have a backup of that theme folder...

Comment: The error message has changed back to the original message now. I tried replacing the config.php with a fresh version but that didnt work and gave me that error you saw

Comment: more specifically I replaced wp-content/themes/stockholm

Answer (score 0):

Their is an issue in one of the theme file.

Do you have any backup of your web site ? Sometime, host provider generate autobackup. If you have one, backup your site.

If you don't have any backup, you could get back access to your wordpress by changing your theme for and other.

To change your theme:

- Log in on your server with ftp,
- Go to `/wp-content/themes/`
- If their isn't an other theme than stockholm, download one theme [here](https://fr.wordpress.org/themes/twentysixteen/). And put uncompresed folder of the theme in `/wp-content/themes/
- Delete the folder `stockholm`(could be nice to backup it before).

After, you should try to install again your stockholm theme, you could try with différent versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will try all this and let you know how I get on!

Comment: I have my site back. Thanks!! In terms of getting the stockholm theme back what would you recommend? Install it fresh?

Comment: I can see you still have the issue. Do again the manipulation to get your site back, disable all your plugins, and try a fresh install of your theme.

Comment: You could also contact [the support of your theme](http://themeforest.net/item/stockholm-a-genuinely-multiconcept-theme/8819050/support) is they know something about this issue

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I have spoken to my theme support. I simply had to update my hosting (123 reg) php to 5.6. when I updated wordpress. No idea I had to do that! Thanks again for the help, Chris.